# Craft 3.1 no longer updates all entries on section save - workaround?

Tags: craft3

Craft 3.1 seems to have removed the functionality where if a section is saved, all entries in that section are re-saved.

This has broken a bunch of functionality that relies on this on a site I've built.

Is there a workaround? Even if it's building another plugin to somehow listen for a save section event (is there such an event) manually triggering the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

> Even if it's building another plugin to somehow listen for a save section event (is there such an event) manually triggering the same thing?

There's an `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_SECTION` event you can listen to where you can put a `ResaveElements` job in the queue for the specific entries in the section that was just saved.